# making sure my array of random values doesn't contain duplicate values

Tags: javascript, jquery, random

I was wondering if anyone can advise how I can make sure the random array I'm generating from another array doesn't contain duplicate values, want to make sure that arr2 contains unique values?

JS

```
var limit = 5,
    i = 0,
    arr1 = [12, 14, 67, 45, 8, 45, 56, 8, 33, 89],
    arr2 = [];

    for ( i; i < limit; i++ ){
        var rand = Math.floor((Math.random()*9)+1);
        arr2.push( arr1[rand] );
    }

    console.log(arr2);
```

Maybe an if statement that compares arr1[rand] with arr2[i] ?

Answer (score 6):

Create a temporary array that is a copy of arr1 containing only unique values:

```
// Copy unique values in arr1 into temp_arr
var temp_obj = {}, temp_arr = [], i;
for(i = arr1.length; i--;)
    temp_obj[arr1[i]] = 1;
for(i in temp_obj) 
    temp_arr.push(i);
```

Then you can remove the element from `temp_arr` each time you add it to `arr2`. Since we used object keys when copying we have strings, so we can use `+` to convert them back to numbers when pushing into `arr2`:

```
arr2.push(+temp_arr.splice(rand, 1)[0]);
```

You should also change how you pick random numbers to:

```
var rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*temp_arr.length);
```

Whole code:

```
var limit = 5,
  arr1 = [12, 14, 67, 45, 8, 45, 56, 8, 33, 89],
  arr2 = [],
  rand, 
  temp_obj = {},
  temp_arr = []
  i;

// Copy unique values from arr1 into temp_arr
for(i = arr1.length; i--;)
    temp_obj[arr1[i]] = 1;
for(i in temp_obj)
    temp_arr.push(i);;

// Move elements one at a time from temp_arr to arr2 until limit is reached
for (var i = limit; i--;){
    rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*temp_arr.length);
    arr2.push(+temp_arr.splice(rand, 1)[0]);
}

console.log(arr2);
```

Comment: Thanks Paul but I need to keep the values in arr1 there, will update that rand though

Comment: There are duplicates in `arr1`, so removing the picked elements doesn't make sure that there are not duplicates in `arr2`.

Comment: @Guffa Ah I see that, updating my answer now.

Comment: @styler I have updated my answer, so that it will keep `arr1` unchanged and have only unique values in `arr2`

Comment: Hi Paul, this looks good! 1 question though, I thought for loops had to have a start value, end value and increment?

Comment: @styler For loops just have three expressions, one that executes before the loop starts, a test to determine if the loop is entered again or finished looping (which executes before every iteration), and one that executes at the end of every iteration.

Comment: @styler In this case I am initializing `i` in the first expression, and in the test that runs before every iteration, I am decrementing `i`. The third expression is empty so nothing happens after each iteration.

Comment: @styler You could initialize i to `0` and iterate forward just as easily. I just prefer to iterate in reverse because it is slightly less code and when you might be conditionally removing DOMElements that you are iterating through in a loop you need to go in reverse. In this case though the direction you iterate really doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2):

The naive `O(n^2)` solution is to simply check each element and see if any other position in the array has the same value.

A linear time solution can be achieved using a hashset data structure. You can hack one in JavaScript using objects:

```
var set = {};
set['0'] = true;
set['1'] = true;

if(set.hasOwnProperty('0')) {
    alert("duplicate 0!");
}
```

If the numbers are integers and relatively small, then you can keep track of them in an array of boolean values.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
for ( i; i < limit; i++ ){
        var rand = Math.floor((Math.random()*9)+1);
        for(j=0; j <  arr1.length; j++)
           if(rand == arr1[j]
           { 
                blnfound = true;
                break;
           }
        if(!blnfound)
        arr2.push( arr1[rand] );
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

See http://bost.ocks.org/mike/shuffle/ for good info on the Fischer/Yates shuffle. For your problem, you could take the first five elements of the shuffled deck.

Answer (score 1):

By using `jQuery.inArray` function :)

```
var limit = 5,
arr1 = [12, 14, 67, 45, 8, 45, 56, 8, 33, 89],
l = arr1.length,
arr2 = [];

while( limit ){
      var tmp = arr1[  Math.random() * l | 0 ];  
      // for unsigned numbers '|0' construction works like Math.floor  
      if( !~$.inArray( tmp, arr2 ) ) { 
       // if not found $.inArray returns -1 ( == ~0 ), then !~-1 == true   
          limit--;
          arr2[ arr2.length ] = tmp;
      } 
} 
console.log( arr2 );
```

Comment: @styler 
~ - bitwise complement; 
! - negate; look at  
[http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/JavaScript/Operators](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/JavaScript/Operators)